# Update column from Base64 to string (natively in SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've been trying to figure this out for two days now and would really appreciate some help. I've imported data from a csv where one field contained html data encoded in base64.

The idea is to loop over every row and run FROM_BASE64 on it.

How do I structure a query that:

1. Loops over all lines
2. Calls FRON_BASE64 for each line
3. Runs UPDATE (or similar functionality) on that same row and column

Context: I'm running MariaDB (MySQL equivalent).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically base64 would be used for binary data. You probably shouldn't store the decoded data in the same column as the base64-coded string. If necessary you should ALTER TABLE to add a new column that is VARBINARY or BLOB type, to hold the binary data.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN BinaryField BLOB;
```

You can then fill that column with an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET BinaryField = FROM_BASE64(EncodedField);
```

Comment: Thank you for that! The current data type of the column is string (I'm importing into a table I didn't make and shouldn't alter). Would I cause issues with `UPDATE MyTable SET BinaryField = FROM_BASE64(Binary Field) ;`. In case I was unclear, I don't need the original Base64  string.

Comment: Figured it out. `update thetable set thecolumn = FROM_BASE64(thecolumn)` did the trick. This was simpler than I anticipated.

Comment: The Base64 column should be `TEXT CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin`.  (There are other options, but this is the most logical.)

Comment: @RickJames, like I mentioned in my comment, the data was being imported into a database belonging to an existing codebase. The only reason the string was base64 encoded was to make it easier to store html in a csv file without causing syntax issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this out:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
f record;
BEGIN
FOR f IN SELECT password FROM <TABLE_NAME>
    LOOP 
    UPDATE <TABLE_NAME> SET password = encode(f.password::bytea , 'base64') where password = f.password;
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).